# How to cancel a running async function in xamarin forms

Tags: android-asynctask, xamarin.forms

I called async function in my code , which call rest service and populate a data structure. But somehow i need to cancel that function before its completion , how can i achieve this.

```
getAdDetails(ad.id,ad.campaign_type);

private async void getAdDetails(int campaign_id, string campaign_type)  {   
// some code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something called "CancelationToken" which is supposed to be for such stuff. 
Another way to do so is by throwing an exception when you want to cancel the process . 
Another way is by having a flag which can be named "ShouldExecute" , and in the method you keep monitoring it.

I also tend to ignore the results which come from the method when they are not needed and let the thread executes in peace but yet ignored when it comes back.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some background logic in your function:

```
 CancellationTokenSource _cancellation;


    public void SomeFunctionToStartDataRefresh(){
       _cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();

    try{
       getAdDetails(id, type, cancellation.Token);
    }catch(OperationCanceledException ex){
      //Operation is cancelled
    }
    }


    private async Task getAdDetails(ad.id,ad.campaign_type);

       private async void getAdDetails(int campaign_id, string campaign_type, CancellationToken token)  {   

       var data = await fetchDatafromServer()
       token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
       await DosomethingWithData();
       token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
       await DoSomethingElseWithData();
    }
```